# It is a very big state: Says Grandpa

Tags: riddle, knowledge

"Wow, this is a very big country, our USA" Said Grandpa. He was looking at the USA map.

"Everyone knows that" My two cents.

> "Did you know that California is twice as big as Nebraska?"
>
> "Could be" I kind of agreed.
>
> "And Florida is twice as big as Louisiana?" He muttered.
>
> "Georgia is big too. It is as big as Arkansas and Alabama combined!"

"No. Really?" Now I got suspicious.

> "Oh and Maryland is as big as 4 states combined. Big states too. One of them is North Dakota"

Now I knew he is in his crazy mode.

> "And tell you what son. This state takes the cake!. It is big as Five
>   states combined. Yes, FIVE!, exactly" said Grandpa.

Now I was curious. What was he talking about? Which state? What was his logic?

Comment: Is the mis-spelling of North Dakota intentional?

Comment: No problem. I find it's always good to check when you're dealing with puzzles.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your Grandpa thinks that

> **Pennsylvania** is a big as **Nebraska, Alabama, California, South Carolina** and **Colorado**

As for the logic:

> If you take the two letters of each state and get the corresponding atomic element, Grandpa is right !
>  - California -> Ca (20) = 2 x Nebraska -> Ne (10)
>  - Florida -> Fl (114) = 2 x Louisiana -> La (57)
>  - Georgia -> Ga (31) = Arkansas + Alabama -> Ar (18) + Al (13)
>  - Maryland -> Md (101) = North Dakota + Nebraska + Alabama + Arkansas -> Nd (60) + Ne (10) + Al (13) + Ar (18)

And for the big state  :

> Pennsylvania -> Pa (91) = Ne (10) + Al (13) + Ca (20) + Sc (21) + Co (27)

Comment: Good Job @Keehaul. Now since you are in that mode. Is there a state that is made up of SIX states? There is.

Comment: Montana is as big as Nebraska, Alabama, Arkansas, California, South Carolina and Colorado :)

Comment: I believe this is the absolute maximum without counting the same state twice. With repetitions, New Hampshire wins, as it is as big as ten times Nebraska, plus Alabama!